# How can I change tint color of UIBarButtonItem while using FBSDK share dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, fbsdk

I have a problem with UIBarButtonItem tintColor.

I have set `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` in AppDelegate for using to default color in the app

But in this screen. It seem can't see the button because it's white!
I used `FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController` to show share popup screen. How can I edit tintColor for this screen?

Edit for explain more.

As suggestions it's work for only this screen. but actually my problem is after I changed this screen to blue color. It will affect to send email screen. So in email screen It seem can't see button too because my navigationbar is blue color. That's tricker. I used UIActicityController to present email screen.

[image]

Comment: change code in appdelegate file
 if([UINavigationBar conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIAppearanceContainer)]) {
        [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

Comment: @Jigar I have to set `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];` because when user click on send to email. button will set to blue as default and my navigation bar color is blue too. so it's will can't see as this button

Answer (score 0):

**objective c**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return YES; 
}
```

**OR**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
if([UINavigationBar conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIAppearanceContainer)]) {
    [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

return YES;
}
```

//*****************************************************************************

**Swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.white
return true
}
```

**or**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
if UINavigationBar is UIAppearanceContainer {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
}
return true
}
```

Comment: Sorry Dishant, Your suggestion can change tintColor but I explained more information in question. so this will not work

Answer (score 0):

If you still haven't figured this one out, what you can do is use the delegates for `FBSDKSharing`.

```
- (IBAction)shareOnFacebook:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentTitle = @"Content Title";
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://example.com/url/to/your/app"];
    content.quote = @"Learn quick and simple ways for people to share content from your app or website to Facebook.";

    // make the changes here; what you want to see in FB Dialog
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarPosition:UIBarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];
    dialog.fromViewController = self;
    dialog.shareContent = content;
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeShareSheet;
    dialog.delegate = self;
    [dialog show];
}

// And change it back in these delegate methods
-(void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results
{
}

-(void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer
{
}

-(void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}
```